# Super key is bound to unknown command, how can I remove it?

Tags: vim

Since a couple of weeks ago every time I press the super key(windows key) vim executes `3p` and some other commands(specified bellow), this all started when I bound my super key to open the terminal by executing `xfce4-terminal --drop-down`. I've already unbound it but the problem is still there.
I want to unbind the super key so I can bind it to some other command.

First thing I tried was to list all commands using `:map` but found nothing related.
This is what I've got:

```
   Y             y$
v  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
v  <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis * :<C-U>call netrw#BrowseXVis()<CR>
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#BrowseX(netrw#GX(),netrw#CheckIfRemote(netrw#GX()))<CR>
n  <C-L>       * :nohl<CR><C-L>
```

Then I executed `vim -w` and stored the output of the super key.
Output:

```
ESC[1;3P
```

Every time I press the super key this was executed.

Comment: Vim doesn't know about the Super key: it can't see it and doesn't provide a mechanism for mapping anything to it so your problem is elsewhere.